# Como hacer un split y guardar los valores en sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

el problema que tengo es el siguiente, yo recibo desde el portal una cadena de texto la cual tengo que cortar y guardar, esta cadena como tal tiene muchos registros y esa es la razon por que la se manda como cadena ya que si la mandara por separado esta pudiera superar los 20,000 registros y para evitar estar mandando una por una al servido se manda como cadena, bueno el problema es que tengo la cadena siguiente (Es un ejemplo pequeño)

> objeto1,[420,47,84,347,50,269,194,58,37,68,49,29,1652], | objeto2,[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1], | objeto3,[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1], | objeto14,[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1], | objeto5,[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], | objeto16,[0,0,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,11], | objeto17,[0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,4], | objeto8,[0,0,0,0,2,0,2,6,0,2,0,0,12], | objeto19,[0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,2,2,10], | objeto10,[0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2], | objeto11,[2,2,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6], | objeto12,[0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2], | objeto14,[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,2], | objeto15,[0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2], |

El primer valor representa el item que serian los objetos y lo que esta entre los corchetes son las veces que se vendio en el mes Enero,Febrero,Marzo, Abril..... y el ultimo numero de ese conjunto seria la suma total de todos los meses y el | seria el separador de cada registro diferente y los valores son separados con comas, ahora lo que yo quiero hacer es insertar toda la informacion en una tabla la cual sus columnas sean "Item" "Enero" "Febrero" "Marzo" .... "Total" respectivamente del orden en el que aparecen en la cadena ya he hecho el split de la cadena pero no se como separarlos por registro solo he podido separarlos por comas ademas que el resultado me lo da en una sola columna y no en varias tampoco sabría como guardar la información si me la da de esa forma. Si los corchetes estorban pueden ser quitados

DECLARE @cadena varchar(MAX) = 'objeto1,[420,47,84,347,50,269,194,58,37,68,49,29,1652]'
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@cadena, ',');

Ese seria el resultado que me da ese split pero no se como hacer que sean varios registros ni como guardalos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y yo quiero que se guarden de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El escenario que planteas:

```
CREATE TABLE datosSplit 
(
    item        varchar(100), 
    Enero       int, 
    Febrero     int, 
    Marzo       int, 
    Abril       int, 
    Mayo        int, 
    Junio       int, 
    Julio       int, 
    Agosto      int, 
    Septiembre  int, 
    Octubre     int, 
    Noviembre   int,
    Diciembre   int,
    Total       int
);
```

Seguro que hay un montón de posibles, para hacer lo que pides. Esta puede ser una manera.

Ojo como no has definido la tabla de destino adecuadamente, la he creado como me parece, columnas como int, por tanto se supone que los valores tienen que ser int.

Voy a hacerlo por partes, para que sea didáctico, y luego ya todo montado, y así ves como se puede realizar.

```
declare @cadena nvarchar(max);
set @cadena = N'objeto1,[420,47,84,347,50,269,194,58,37,68,49,29,1652], | objeto2,[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1], | objeto3,[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1], | objeto14,[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1], | objeto5,[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], | objeto16,[0,0,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,11], | objeto17,[0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,4], | objeto8,[0,0,0,0,2,0,2,6,0,2,0,0,12], | objeto19,[0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,2,2,10], | objeto10,[0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2], | objeto11,[2,2,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6], | objeto12,[0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2], | objeto14,[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,2], | objeto15,[0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2], |';
Set @cadena = Replace((Replace(@cadena,'[','')),']','');
```

Del origen de los datos, no me interesan los corchetes, no me aportan valor. En otro escenario puede que sean muy interesantes, pero tal cual has expuesto, no me hacen falta, y por eso los elimino de la entrada.

En vez de usar `split_String` para separar, voy a usar otra función para delimitar strings que además me aporta el orden del *spliteo*.

[DelimitedSplit8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function)

Hay otra nueva en el mismo enlace, que puede tener un mejor rendimiento, pero como ya tenía esta, para el escenario y no va a varia tanto, pues esta usaré.

Para no meter un montón de código que no aporta nada, en la explicación obviaré como se llena la variable `@cadena`, pero es necesario en todas las fases, igual que en el primer código expuesto.

```
With R as (
    SELECT fn.ItemNumber, fn.Item
    FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@cadena, '|') fn
)
select * from R
```

[image: Res1]

Tenemos por tanto lo mismo que habías conseguido, pero con un `ItemNumber`.

Ahora necesitamos splitear de nuevo cada Item. Pero en este caso por la coma.

```
With R as (
    SELECT fn.ItemNumber, fn.Item
    FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@cadena, '|') fn
)
, R2 as (
     Select r.Item AS item, 
            trim(fn.Item) as Elemento, 
            fn.ItemNumber as numElemento
    from R cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(R.item,',') fn
    where len(fn.Item) >0
)
select * from R2
```

[image: Res2]

Ahora tenemos cada `Item`, pero además tenemos también separado en filas, el objeto que corresponde siempre con el `NumElemento=1` y sus valores con `NumElemento entre  2 y 14`.

Si esas filas, las convertimos de nuevo a columnas, utilizando pivot, se parecerá al objetivo final.

```
With R as (
    SELECT fn.ItemNumber, fn.Item
    FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@cadena, '|') fn
)
, R2 as (
     Select r.Item AS item, 
            trim(fn.Item) as Elemento, 
            fn.ItemNumber as numElemento
    from R cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(R.item,',') fn
    where len(fn.Item) >0
)
select * from R2 
pivot (max(Elemento) for numElemento in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14]))pvt
```

[image: Res3]

Por último, solo nos queda montar la sentencia de insercíon y excluir el `Item`, que  ya no aporta valor, utilizando las columnas `pvt.[1]` a `pvt.[14]`.

**Solución**

```
declare @cadena nvarchar(max);
set @cadena = N'objeto1,[420,47,84,347,50,269,194,58,37,68,49,29,1652], | objeto2,[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1], | objeto3,[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1], | objeto14,[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1], | objeto5,[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], | objeto16,[0,0,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,11], | objeto17,[0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,4], | objeto8,[0,0,0,0,2,0,2,6,0,2,0,0,12], | objeto19,[0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,2,2,10], | objeto10,[0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2], | objeto11,[2,2,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6], | objeto12,[0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2], | objeto14,[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,2], | objeto15,[0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2], |';
Set @cadena = Replace((Replace(@cadena,'[','')),']','');

With R as (
    SELECT fn.ItemNumber, fn.Item
    FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@cadena, '|') fn
)
, R2 as (
     Select r.Item AS item, 
            trim(fn.Item) as Elemento, 
            fn.ItemNumber as numElemento
    from R cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(R.item,',') fn
    where len(fn.Item) >0
), pivote as (
select * from R2 
pivot (max(Elemento) for numElemento in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14]))pvt 
)
Insert into dbo.datosSplit
    ([item], 
    [Enero], 
    [Febrero], 
    [Marzo], 
    [Abril], 
    [Mayo], 
    [Junio], 
    [Julio], 
    [Agosto], 
    [Septiembre], 
    [Octubre], 
    [Noviembre], 
    [Diciembre], 
    [Total])
Select p.[1],
    p.[2],
    p.[3],
    p.[4],
    p.[5],
    p.[6],
    p.[7],
    p.[8],
    p.[9],
    p.[10],
    p.[11],
    p.[12],
    p.[13],
    p.[14]
from pivote p;
```

[image: ResultadoFinal]

[Pivot simple](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/16/pivot-simple-como-hacer-y-entenderlo-paso-por-paso/)

[Cte Correlativas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-2-correlativos/)